# What is thebarefootwriter.com?

Tags: publishing

I received an email for this today. First of all, is it legit or is it a scam of some kind? How does it work? That is, what are you writing for - a web site,  a paper publication? Who decides what you'll write?

Comment: Just want to leave [this article](https://workfromhomejourney.com/is-the-barefoot-writer-a-scam-heres-my-review) here because it lists a lot of the negative feedback. And I want to comment that I checked out what I could find, too - nothing to add to [this answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/34517/23159), except for my opinion: "Stay away from this scam." Also, being contacted is always a bad sign. If they were really a good website, why would they send out masses of e-mails to people who don't already know about them and ask them to subscribe to something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can see, you spend money to join a "club" that provides help for your writing (including a magazine).

Here are several problems with the company:

First, there's the fact that the website has this extreme emphasis on the words FREE, RICH, and MONEY (emphasis not added).

Second, this [article](http://accrispin.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-barefoot-writers-club.html) goes on a long rant against the website.

Third, the emphasis on secrecy is another flag.

Fourth, I highly doubt that the company cares about your writing and only cares about your money being in their pocket.

Fifth, check out the suspicion sign up [page](https://www.awai.com/p/is/tbw/).

I would stay away from The Barefoot Writer. They might be helpful, but you can probably find better material at a better price without all the constant badgering for money. I think it is a perfectly legal scam. As in they aren't breaking the law, but they are basically cheating you.